# Tentando fazer alert em todos os href da página mas só um é exibido

Tags: jquery, html, alert

Estou fazendo uns testes e me deparei com um esse erro muito chato.

É fácil explicar: eu quero que o JQuery dê o `alert` em todos os `<a>` da página, mas ele só da `alert` uma vez e nada mais. Vamos aos códigos:

```
<ul>

<li> <a href='http://www.google.com.br' class='tooltip'> Não clique </a></li>

<li> <a href='http://www.youtube.com.br' class='tooltip'> Não clique </a></li>

<li> <a href='http://www.redtube.com.br' class='tooltip'> Não clique </a></li>

</ul>
```

Daí eu fiz o JQuery, que é simples:

```
<script>

/*$(document).ready(function(e) {

      var href = $('.tooltip').attr('href');
    alert(href);
});*/


$(window).scroll(function(){
    var href = $('.tooltip').attr('href');
    alert(href);

    })

</script>
```

Comment: tenta mudar o jquery pra `$('href').each(function(){var href = $('.tooltip').attr('href');
    alert(href);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você seleciona os elementos pela Class, o Jquery vai armazenar todas as ocorrências em um vetor. Portanto, o correto é:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var hrefArray = $('.tooltip');

    for(var i = 0; i < hrefArray.length; i++){
        alert(hrefArray[i].href);
    }
});
```

Comment: certinho vlw ;3 'ajudo pra caramba